# Связь и сумма полей в django

Tags: django-orm, python, web-apps, django

Есть модель

```
class City(models.Model):
    city_people = models.CharField()

class People(models.Model):
    people_culture = models.IntegerField()
    people_science = models.IntegerField()
    people_total = models.IntegerField()
    people_city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

Вопросы:

1. Как в модели указать что поле
       "people total" это сумма всех полей?
2. Как указать в модели что, поле
       "people total" из таблицы People это
       тоже самое, что и "city_people" в таблице "City"?

Comment: Что значит указать?

Вы хотите чтобы при изменении полей people_culture и people_science их сумма записывалась в People. people_total и она же в City.people_total?

Comment: Да, такое возможно? либо сразу записывала в city.people.

Comment: Как вариант, переписывай метод .save() модели People и в нем пиши логику которая будет отслеживать изменение интересуемых полей, просчитывать сумму и записывать в _total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто указать никак нельзя.

Вам нужно переопределить метод save модели People.

```
class People(models.Model):
    people_culture = models.IntegerField()
    people_science = models.IntegerField()
    people_total = models.IntegerField()
    people_city = models.ForeignKey(City)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.people_total = self.people_culture + self.people_science
        self.people_city.city_people = self.people_total
        self.people_city.save()
        super(People, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Таким образом при каждом сохранении модели (создание, изменение) в ее поле будет записыватся вычисленное значение.

Обратите внимание, что в вашей структуре к City может относится несколько People, и этот код будет записывать в City.city_people только сумму последнего измененного People.

Comment: А самой базе нельзя это сказать делать? Что-то вроде city people = models.Sum(people culture+ people science)?

Comment: Нет, ничего такого через django ORM базе сказать нельзя.

Нечто подобное можно сказать базе mysql используя хранимые процедуры.
Но тогда вам прийдется делать raw SQL запросы и не получится использовать ORM.

Либо вы можете не хранить поле people_total вообще а доставть его из базы как сумму нужных полей. Но опять таки django ORM вам тут не поможет, нужно будет писать SQL запрос самому.

Comment: Спасибо, за подробный ответ. Очень помогли.